# View button that links to current node

Tags: 7, views, nodes, navigation

I'm trying to create this button in my views with a custom text, that needs to link to the current node.

I know you can use links and that works, but.. i need something like a variable that makes the link always go to the current node.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can add field "path" to your view.

Comment: @lamp5 but.. it only shows the path? How to get it in a link?

Comment: You can Rewrite the output of the Path field to something like `<a href="[path]">[title]</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

The field `Content: Link` allows you to enter `Text to display`.

1. Add a new Field **Content: Link**
2. Under **Text to display** enter **Bestel nu**

Easy :)

For more complex changes you can use the "Rewrite the output of this field" option on the "Content: Link" field. It's more reliable to use this field than Path.

You can use "Global: Custom text" field to construct some output (also "Rewrite the output of this field") using the tokens for the fields listed above it, but it isn't necessary in this case.